# Display Splash image according to iPhone size

Tags: ios

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==667)
{

    animatedSplashScreen.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i4.png"],nil];    }

if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==736)
{
    animatedSplashScreen.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i2.png"],nil];    }
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)
{
    animatedSplashScreen.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i5.png"],nil];
}
```

Comment: but output is coming only if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are not using  `Asset Catalog`.  It is a very easy procedure through which you can  add icons and splash in asset catalog.

[image: First]

---

[image: Second]

---

[image: Third]

---

Referred from [this](http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.in/2014/03/howto-add-splash-screen-application.html).

---

Alternative way, **if you have do it programmatically**, then you can put the check of iPhone screen size by these following macro- :

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define SCREEN_WIDTH [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Comment: i want set splash image using only programmatically

Comment: @GauravSrivastava Is there  any specific reason for that? As in your question it is not specified anywhere. Why not use the new features of xcode rather doing the things in  old way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LauchScreen.xib. Put an Image view as of xib's main view size. Use autolayout to pin it with all four side.

ie. 1.Trailing space to superView
    2.Leading space to superView
    3.Bottom space to superView
    4.Top sapace to superView